# css top property is not working properly on animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

There is an issue with this property, while trying to animate a text, I'm using a text cursor to follow the text but on certain point of the animation this "cursor" (just a line) doesn't do what I put on the code, so... I don't know what is happening to it.
Here you have the piece of code:

```css
.code {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  height: 180px;
  animation: coding 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: steps(20);
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes coding {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 230px;
  }
}
.code p {
  color: red;
  width: 258px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.code span  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  color: red;
  animation: cods 7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  font-size: 20px;
}
@keyframes cods {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
  }
  75% {
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="code">
    <p>&lt;I am the animated text&gt;</p><span>|</span>
</div>
```

as you see here, the cursor first go to the left and then go to the bottom, but that's not on the code. from 50% to 75% I'm telling: "go 20px down" and then from 75% to 100%: "go left".

Comment: The `left` property is not animatable between its default value of `auto` and an absolute value.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing `left: 0` into `right: 100%` in the 100% keyframe!